# How to start a new activity while always keeping the gallery?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am making a memory game using the gallery view. I want all the cards to be shown at the bottom and when the user picks one card from the gallery the particular card is displayed above it(in the image view). When the user touches this card, the card should turn (using flip animation) and the front of the card should be displayed (which should be a new activity). During this flip and all the time I want to display the gallery at the bottom. How can i do this? I have the following code which has no errors but the app crashes before starting. On viewing the log cat it suggests an error while starting the new acidity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GalleryActivity extends Activity { 
    //---the images to display---
    Integer[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.you,
            R.drawable.date,
            R.drawable.competition,
            R.drawable.contacts,
            R.drawable.memory,
            R.drawable.mission,
            R.drawable.recognition,
            R.drawable.report,
            R.drawable.stallion,
            R.drawable.strategy,
            R.drawable.team

    };
    ImageView youview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);



        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "card" + (position + 1) + " selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //---display the images selected---
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
                imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            }
        });

        youview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.you);
        youview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryActivity.this, You.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Context context;
        int itemBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            context = c;
            //---setting the style---
            TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);            

            itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);                

            a.recycle();
        }

        //---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount() {
            return imageIDs.length;
        }


        //---returns the item---
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

         //---returns the ID of an item---
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }      

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));                  
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }            
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
            return imageView;
        }
    }



}
```

Here is the layout that I am using:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#006600">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choose the card" 
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>    

<Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/gallery1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest using fragments within the activity. The gallery can be in its own fragment and will remain unaffected by changes to the remaining section. Something like the Master-Detail design pattern might work well in this case.

Comment: Can we see your layout files please? I would use a fragment as well, and make sure that you are adding the fragment to either a Relative or Frame Layout so it can appear above the gallery etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a fragment for this as so:

```
private void addCardFragment() {
    String fragmentTag = getFragmentTag();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_in, R.animator.card_flip_out);

    CardFragment fragment = new CardFragment();
    //set bundle with argument for image id to show if fragment

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_relative_or_frame_layout, CardFragment, fragmentTag);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentTransaction = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Droid. Now, I want to make the same but without using fragments as I want to call a new activity later.Kindly suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fragments is really the only way to go here. If you want to keep gallery present, you need to toggle the card in a fragment, not in another activity.

Comment: Thanks Droid. I will try to implement it :-)